# RAML -> APIKit flows:how to generate representations based on Accept header?

Tags: header, mule

I have a RAML spec with both application/xml and application/json as representation for the response body, based on the HTTP Accept request header. APIKit only generates flows for one of the two formats. What can I do to create a mocking service that responds with both json and xml based on this construct?

Comment: based on RAML i  created a flow that is working fine for Accept = application/json but with Accept = application/xml getting below error org.mule.module.apikit.exception.UnsupportedMediaTypeException

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by **updating the RAML file**
Update **Accept in header**
[image]

Also updated **Response body** with 2 example 
[image]

apikit routes based on resources and methods only. 
You'll need to use a **choice router** to set the different payloads depending on the **'accept'**